# Is there a jQuery poll plugin?

Tags: jquery

Looking to make a simple poll, does not even need to be cookie based I don't care how many votes are cast. Is there a plugin or something simple like this?

Comment: it should be fairly easy to write one yourself...

Comment: But is there a way to remember poll votes without having to connect to a database etc..?

Comment: So which plugin did you use ? Kindly tell me because I am having the need of such a plugin too.

Answer (score 6):

This is a useful tutorial - let me know if it works for you

[using jQuery to build a poll](http://net.tutsplus.com/javascript-ajax/creating-a-dynamic-poll-with-jquery-and-php/)

Here is a demo of the poll working. It uses flatfiledb to store the votes:-

[live demo](http://net.tutsplus.com/demos/test_poll/)

Answer (score 1):

Search in the plugins area of jquery turned up

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jPoll

Comment: Yeah I had downloaded that to play with, but it does not keep track of votes.  Is there a way to make a "mock" database or something to connect and store?

Comment: You'd need to create a server side page that accepts the votes etc from the above plugin. You could do it through xml files if you didn't have access to a DB system.. Again would be down to server side page.